# Handling missing data points with mean

Tags: machine-learning

I have seen a lot of datasets where missing values are replaced with the mean. What if data was not normally distributed, does it still make sense to replace missing values with mean if one would choose to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, replacing missing values with the mean (on fact,  I believe the median is more popular) of the variable that is missing across other observations is not a good approach, even if the variable is normally distributed. It's more of an initial try one can implement without much effort,  results in a value that is usually not totally absurd and *if* the variable does not matter too much may not affect modelling results all that much.

There are substantially better other methods that can make use of other information (e.g. multiple imputation, knn imputation etc.). E.g. let's say you want to predict what income people have, but for some records age is missing. Yet,  you know whether they are "in school", "receiving other education/training" "employed", "unemployed" or "retired". Would you put the mean age of all people for a record with missing age that says the person is still in school?